# how to get all files name from a folder in storage android

Tags: android, file, storage

I am stuck here while i am getting files from directory/folder, but here it showing list of size is 0.

```
val path: String = "Keeper"
val folder: File = null
if (Build.VERSION_CODES.R > Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) {
  folder = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path + "//" + path)
} else {
  folder = File(
    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).path + "//" + path
)
}

val files: Array<File> = folder.listFiles()
Log.e("Files", "Size: " + files.size)
for (i in files.indices) {
   Log.e("Files", "FileName:" + files[i].name)
}
```

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/Keeper/KeeperDB.db: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Android 10 it is working fine, but in 11 not working.
So, any idea where i am wrong here??

Comment: You do not have filesystem-level access to files in `Documents/` on Android 11+, except for files that your app created.

Comment: how can check  that access

Comment: How did that file land there? It was not done by your app?